# Confused about printing "object.value" in nativescript-vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Below nativescript-vue code I'm parsing a json file and trying to print it, but some reason I can't print `json.city.value` in Label, but I can print it inside script part, inside `readFromJson` method `console.log(json.city.value)` is working, and in Label tag also I can print `parsedJson.city`, but not `parsedJson.city.value` is value a keyword or preserved variable for nativescript or vuejs?
Below you can find, simplified code of what I'm trying to do.

```js
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Welcome to NativeScript-Vue!"/>
        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
            <Label class="message" :text="parsedJson.city.value" col="0" row="0"/>
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script >

  let json2 = '{"approved":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"valueInfo":{}},"city":{"type":"String","value":"Konstanz","valueInfo":{}},"street":{"type":"String","value":"Reichenaustraße 11","valueInfo":{}},"contractNumber":{"type":"String","value":"3847384contractNumber","valueInfo":{}},"description":{"type":"String","value":"","valueInfo":{}}}'

  export default {
    data() {

      return {
        msg: 'Hello World!',
        parsedJson: {}
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log("mounted is worked")
      console.log("json to parse is: " + json2)
      this.readFromJson(json2) 

    },
    methods: {
      readFromJson(input) {
        console.log("inside readfromjson")
        var json = JSON.parse(input)
        console.log("parsed city.value is: " + json.city.value)
        this.parsedJson = json
      }

    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
    ActionBar {
        background-color: #53ba82;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .message {
        vertical-align: center;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20;
        color: #333333;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess is that it immediately tries to use a value that is undefined. parsedJson is defined as {} and doesn't get initialized till later. Maybe try initializing it an empty string:

```
parsedJson: {
  city: {
     value:''
  }
}
```